# How to get Date in proper Format

Tags: android, adb

Using the windows shell when i try to query the `mmssms.db` like

```
sqlite> select address, date, body from sms;
```

it gives me the date in some weird format, how can i get it in proper Date format. Screen shot is attached.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a date(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...) function for sqlite, see here - http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

or the strftime(format, timestring) looks like it would work better

so something like:

sqlite> select address, strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', date), body from sms;

Comment: It's milliseconds and unixepoch, so query will be: `select address, strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', date/1000, 'unixepoch'), body from sms;`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a time date stamp. Look into the formatting and casting

This is TSQL specific but the concept is the same if the syntax varies slightly

http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/

edit: Not my blog just a link I googled that covered what you are trying to accomplish faster than me typing it out.

edit #2 : Just to be thorough and unbiased, w3schools has a good tutorial on this here:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It is a java timestamp in milliseconds..